# Software packages that can construct feature representation for a given text file using N-gram model

Tags: r, machine-learning, matlab, text-mining, natural-language

Are there any open source software packages, (Java, Matlab, R) that can generate a feature representation for a text document using N-gram model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vowpal wabbit](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki) can do that automatically (via `--ngram` flag) but it uses a highly convoluted way to store the resulting representation (a binary hash map) so it is not trivial to get a human-readable version of that.

If the data set in question is not enormous then one can construct ngram features with a bit of python scripting by relying on `nltk` package:

`>>> help(nltk.ngrams)

Help on function ngrams in module nltk.util:

ngrams(sequence, n, pad_left=False, pad_right=False, pad_symbol=None)

A utility that produces a sequence of ngrams from a sequence of items.

For example:`
  `>>> ngrams([1,2,3,4,5], 3)

    [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]`
  `Use ingram for an iterator version of this function.  Set pad_left
    or pad_right to true in order to get additional ngrams:`
`>>> ngrams([1,2,3,4,5], 2, pad_right=True)

    [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, None)]`